# Starting a sentence with "as also"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-starts

Is it grammatically correct to start a sentence with "As also"?

I guess that the following example is not grammatically correct:

> **As also** the product includes a clippy-like helper.

while this one is correct or sounds better at least:

> **Moreover**, the product includes a clippy-like helper.

Comment: Many school teachers and style guides say to not start a sentence with a conjunction. 'As also' sounds more like a prepositional phrase; depending on the rest of the sentence this could be perfectly fine, or if the prepositional phrase stands alone, then not fine.

Comment: Why would you *want* to include a "referenceless" ***As*** at the start of your first example? If you simply don't know normal English, perhaps you should be asking on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers *As also the product includes a clippy-like helper, there is no need for a widget-driver*. Not good English, but just about grammatical (late on a Friday afternoon).

Comment: An alternate, though still not the best restatement, for that sentence would be, "*Since* the product includes a clippy-like helper, there is no need for a widget-driver."  (Personally, I'm more confused by the "clippy-like helper"!) LOL!

Comment: @WS2: OP has put full stops at the end of his "sentences". As Mitch points out, it's fine as a *dependent prepositional phrase* shifted to the front of a longer sentence, but that's not the usage being queried here.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: Presumably it means the [crappy little animated "pop-up helper"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Assistant) Microsoft eventually had the grace to put down.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, guys. I asked this question because I'm trying to prove to my colleague that the first example is wrong (the one with "as also"). Indeed, maybe I should've asked this question at English Learners.

Comment: @bahrep: The thing is, you don't really provide enough *context*. If you're going to start a sentence with something like *also, moreover, besides which, additionally*, you must remember these words need to have *something previously-mentioned* that they can refer to. And even then they don't really mean much in a "product description" context, where *every* feature you mention (apart from the first one) could be made "attention-grabbingly emphatic" with some rubbish like *"Not only does it have all those features! - it **even** has this one!"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers aww. OK, the actual sentence was `As also Small Business Server includes Windows Server 2008
R2.`. I just couldn't prove that the sentence is wrong myself and googling don't reveal any similar examples.

Comment: @bahrep: Google reports not a single instance of the text **"As also Small Business Server includes"**, but wherever you got it from is probably an unreliable source. Unless it's part of a dependent prepositional phrase, you can't "grammatically" start a sentence in this way. And even if it were to be valid, the word ***also*** would normally be better positioned - giving, for example, *As Small Business Server **also** includes X, you don't need to buy Y*.

Comment: I might just use 'As the product also includes a clippy-like helper.'                                 But I'd call this a sentence fragment, not a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the formulation "as also", but because of the "as" I'm expecting something of the style

```
 As he can run 100 metres in 9.8 seconds he's a great addition to our relay team
```

that is I'm expecting the sentence to explain a consequence. You say that "Moreover" is an alternative, so I'm interpreting your intention is to expand on some previously defined product capabilities.

```
 Moreover, the product does XXX and YYYY
```

This is grammatical, but whether this works well depends upon the context. Marketing blurb can all too easily descend into a breathless list of positive attributes, linked with "In addition" and "Moreover". I would usually simply use a bullet list which then needs no connectors such as "in addition".

See [this reference](http://www.stickyball.net/esl-writing-exercises-and-activities.html?id=299) for some more examples.